# How do I turn off the perl-specific parts of find-requires when building an RPM?

Tags: perl, rpm, rpmbuild

rpmbuild will scan Perl modules to find Perl dependencies, but it doesn't understand optional modules and its generated Perl module requirement list will often be wrong.  How can I turn this feature off *just for Perl dependencies*, but leave the rest of the automatic features on?  I've tried `AutoReqProv: no` but that appears to turn off all automatic dependency and provides scanning.

This is on CentOS 5.8 using RPM 4.4.2.3.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude specific file or dir from scan path for dependencies, try something like this:

```
%filter_requires_in %{_datarootdir}/%{name}/extra
%filter_setup
```

You can use following macros:

- %filter_from_requires
- %filter_requires_in

These are all macros from 'redhat-rpm-config' RPM package. For more information take a look in a file:

```
/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/macros
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/lib/rpm/macros.perl
```

There are all global macros defined, you could define them to something that does nothing. Otherwise it will be most likely in the generic macros in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a shot next time I build that rpm.